# Is it possible to update MySQL version without updating PHP version?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mariadb

My Current MySQL version is `MySQL, 5.0`, given in detail below:

```
mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.96, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

And, my Current PHP version is `5.4.45`

I want to update my MYSQL version to the latest available `MariaDB 10.1 version` without updating PHP version.

**Will updating MySQL without updating PHP create any issues in PHP websites?**

My Server Team asked me to update MySQL version as I am facing downtime issue with my PHP websites.

Server Team send me the below email for updating MySQL version and asking for permission to update. Please check and let me know if I must go for update or not.

------------------------ SERVER EMAIL -------------------------

*I have investigated the server and found that, similar to the issue
previously reported in ticket #1953153, your server experienced a
large spike in %user CPU usage which indicates that an application was
overloading the server. It seems that this issue may have again been
due to excessive MySQL activity across multiple accounts.*

*I did notice that your server is running a very outdated version of MySQL, 5.0:*

```
mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.96, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
readline 5.1
```

*I highly recommend that you allow us to upgrade MySQL on this server
for general stability improvements that should hopefully prevent
queries from hanging and causing excessive load in the future. We can
upgrade MySQL on your server to the latest available MariaDB 10.1
version.*

*In order to upgrade your MySQL service we will need to go through the
following steps:*

*1) We will check for and repair any errors in the databases in your server*

*2) We will remove any "extra" databases created by our technicians for
backup purposes*

*3) We will backup all the databases on your server*

*4) We will upgrade MySQL*

*5) We will run mysql_upgrade*

*6) We will repair any errors found in the databases post-upgrade*

*7) We will recompile PHP/Apache to include the new version of MySQL*

*8) We will check the websites using MySQL for issues*

*9) We will recompile cPanel's internal PHP installation*

*Please note:*

*If you plan on upgrading to ( or beyond ) MYSQL 5.6, any databases
that were created before MYSQL4.1 will have issues with their password
and it will need to be reset due to the changes from 5.5-5.6 and the
requirements thereof.*

*An upgrade to MySQL can take a while and will cause PHP scripts that
rely on MySQL databases to stop working until PHP is recompiled to
support the new version of MySQL. Furthermore, several cPanel services
will also be unavailable during this time. Plan for the process to
take at least an hour, more if upgrading through several major
versions of MySQL. We've seen this process take 30 minutes on some
servers, and have it take 4 hours on others. Since this upgrade can
last some time, and will make your websites unavailable during that
time, please let us know if we should schedule this for off-peak hours
or if we should proceed with the upgrade as soon as possible once we
have confirmation from you.*

Comment: You could get in trouble when PHP's mysql client is to old (protocol differences) to connect with the newer server..

Comment: My server team will manage the MySQL updation task, only thing they want make sure that my PHP websites will not have any issue.

Comment: It should work in most combinations.  If one (php or mysql) is a decade older than the other, there _might_ be trouble -- _trouble that you need to discover and fix_.  Example: using the deprecated "mysql_*" API.

Comment: @RickJames No my current MySQL version is not that much older, its MySQL 5.0. I am going for update and will try to resolve if any issue comes.

Comment: Get a backup before you do anything.